# Increase in SMPS output voltage with RF amplifier as a load

Tags: dc

I am trying to use an SMPS of 50 V output ,16 A current capacity from meanwell make for powering one of the RF amplifier operating at 13.56 MHz.
The amplifier is evaluation module of MRF300AN.

The issue is that as soon as i increase the drive power to the amplifier, the voltage on the SMPS goes on increasing from 50 V to 100 V and more.
( for eg: When I give around 0 dBm , voltage is ok, but as we go more around 10 dBm,the voltage from the SMPS increases to 82 V and goes on increasing with more drive power)

Have tried with a benctop switching power supply from APLAB too, here the issue is different. The output voltage goes down and that too without much current drawn, much lesser than the Cc limit set.

I felt that could be an issue with RF superimposing on DC lines and creating some issue in control/sense circuitry in the power supply.

But the same issue is not happening with MRF 101 eval board, even if the whole electrical environment is almost same. The power supply works fine in this case.

Can anybody give a hint on what could cause such problems with switching power supplies. I would like to understand and resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: RF noise that makes the voltage regulator 'drive mad'. You have to install a RFC choke.

Comment: Thanks for the input Marko,I will try using an RFC choke and check the behaviour.

Comment: Hi Marko, Adding an RF choke did solve the problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, RF generally upsets power supplies (esp. SMPS) by getting on the feedback line.  A pi filter very close to the feedback input (either CRC or CLC with a ferrite) will help.  Choose values based on your RF frequency.

Comment: Thanks Cristobol, will try using a filter or RFC choke and feedthrough filters and test the system again.